# Align <button> element bottom inside a flex-grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align-bottom a button in the 2 column. I tried almost everything including position:absolute and relative.

Here a link explaining what I am doing https://www.beerstrot.it/cavecchia.github.io/colonna.html.

It seems the only way to do it is using grid-template with 2 row on the second column.

Here html code:

```
<div class="grid-container extra-space">
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div class="cell">
            <h2>Can i vertically align bottom the blue button?</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x grid-margin-y">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1920" alt="Roll Ca&#x27; Vecchia Beerstrot">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Hi there,</h3>
                    <p>button align bottom?</p>
                    <button  type="button" class="button small align-self-bottom" style="margin-bottom: 0;">Aggiungi al Carrello</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="box-image">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1920" alt="Roll Ca&#x27; Vecchia Beerstrot">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Hi there,</h3>
                    <p>I am a much longer desription and it is ok the button is at the very end of the container so no need to push it at the end. <br>Well actually since i am a test i do add to the height of the container so the container is bigger and i go deep down to the earth</p>
                    <div  class="">
                        <button  type="button" class="button small" style="margin-bottom: 0;">Aggiungi al Carrello</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <h2>If I use grid-template it works</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">
            <section id="page">
                <div class="item-image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1920" alt="Roll Ca&#x27; Vecchia Beerstrot"></div>
                <div class="item-text">
                    <h3>Hi there,</h3>
                    <p>button align bottom?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item-button">
                    <button  type="button" class="button small" style="margin-bottom: 0;">Aggiungi al Carrello</button>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <section id="page">
                <div class="item-image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1920" alt="Roll Ca&#x27; Vecchia Beerstrot"></div>
                <div class="item-text">
                    <h3>Hi there,</h3>
                    <p>I am a much longer desription and it is ok the button is at the very end of the container so no need to push it at the end. <br>Well actually since i am a test i do add to the height of the container so the container is bigger and i go deep down to the earth</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item-button">
                    <button  type="button" class="button small" style="margin-bottom: 0;">Aggiungi al Carrello</button>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here the CSS:

```
//test not working
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(140px, 1fr) 3fr;
    grid-auto-rows: min-content;
    gap: 20px;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    background: rgba(lightpink, 0.4);
}
.box {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 1;
    background-color: rgba(green, 0.2);
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

//test grid-templates and it works
#page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template:  "item-image  item-text" 3fr
                    "item-image  item-button" auto;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(140px, 1fr) 3fr;
    column-gap: 20px;
    background: rgba(lightpink, 0.4);
    .item-image {
        background-color: rgba(lightblue, 0.4);
        grid-area: item-image;
    }
    .item-text {
        background-color: rgba(yellow, 0.4);;
        grid-area: item-text;
    }
    .item-button {
        background-color: rgba(red, 0.4);
        grid-area: item-button;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

I tried to vertically align bottom an element inside a row using Flexbox properties, but I was not able to find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="grid-container extra-space">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
            <div class="cell">
                <h2>Can i vertically align bottom the blue button?</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x grid-margin-y">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div>
                        <img height="150px" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1920" alt="Roll Ca&#x27; Vecchia Beerstrot">
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3>Hi there,</h3>
                        <p>button align bottom?</p>
                        <button  type="button" class="button small align-self-bottom" style="margin-bottom: 0;">Aggiungi al Carrello</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="box-image">
                        <img height="150px" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1920" alt="Roll Ca&#x27; Vecchia Beerstrot">
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3>Hi there,</h3>
                        <p>I am a much longer desription and it is ok the button is at the very end of the container so no need to push it at the end. <br>Well actually since i am a test i do add to the height of the container so the container is bigger and i go deep down to the earth</p>
                        <div  class="">
                            <button  type="button" class="button small" style="margin-bottom: 0;">Aggiungi al Carrello</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: minmax(140px, 1fr) 3fr;
            grid-auto-rows: min-content;
            gap: 20px;
            margin-top: 2rem;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
            background: rgba(255, 182, 193, 0.178);
        }
        .box {
            grid-column-start: 2;
            grid-column-end: 2;
            grid-row-start: 1;
            grid-row-end: 1;
            background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.155);
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi Clèment, welcome to SO! Please explain what you did and why. Just dumping your code and have people search for it is not acceptable on SO.